# How to split this Bingo game into 3 separate classes?

Tags: java, object-oriented, game

I have a single file of a java Bingo program that I want to split into three separate classes (BingoMain, BingoGUI, BingoCard). Extending a program across several files is something I have never really done, so a little help is appreciated. I also want to add the ability to extend the current program to include functionality for up to 5 players. I know that all the code I need is pretty much in here already. Which lines/parts would go in which class and what would I edit in order to add the desired functionality? I don't expect any code, just some directions to get me on my way.

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import javax.swing.*;



public class Bingo extends JFrame {

      public static void main (String[] args) {

         Integer[][] bingoCard = new Integer[5][5];
         boolean[][] called = new boolean[][] {  {false,false,false,false,false},
                                                 {false,false,false,false,false},
                                                 {false,false,true ,false,false},
                                                 {false,false,false,false,false},
                                                 {false,false,false,false,false}};
         JFrame myBingoGUI;
         /*
          *  Fill an array with 15 numbers (1-15) for the "B" column, put the numbers in random order, and
          *  put the first 5 of those numbers in the "B" column of the bingo card. Continue with I,N,G,and O columns.
          */
         Integer[] row = new Integer[15];

         for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            fillRow(row, i*15+1);
            randomize (row);
            putRowInBingoCard(bingoCard,i,row);
         }
         /*
          *   Print the bingo card.
          */
         myBingoGUI=new JFrame();
         myBingoGUI.setSize(250, 250);
         myBingoGUI.setLocation(400, 400);
         myBingoGUI.setTitle("BINGO");
         myBingoGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         myBingoGUI.setVisible(true);
         Container myContentPane = myBingoGUI.getContentPane();
         JTextArea myTextArea = new JTextArea();
         myTextArea.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN,14));
         myContentPane.add(myTextArea);
         myTextArea.append(toStringBingoCard(bingoCard,called));
         System.out.println(toStringBingoCard(bingoCard,called));
      /*
       *   Play the game:   
       */
         while (!winner(called)) {
            String calledNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a BINGO call:");
            int calledColumn=-1;
            /*
             *   The first character of the input string is converted to a column number between 0 and 4
             */
            if (Character.toUpperCase(calledNumber.charAt(0))=='B') calledColumn=0;
            if (Character.toUpperCase(calledNumber.charAt(0))=='I') calledColumn=1;
            if (Character.toUpperCase(calledNumber.charAt(0))=='N') calledColumn=2;
            if (Character.toUpperCase(calledNumber.charAt(0))=='G') calledColumn=3;
            if (Character.toUpperCase(calledNumber.charAt(0))=='O') calledColumn=4;  
            /*
             *  The remainder of the input string is converted to an integer
             */
            int calledValue = Integer.parseInt(calledNumber.substring(1,calledNumber.length()));
            /*
             *   The matrix of called numbers is update to show the number has been called.
             */
            for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
               if (bingoCard[i][calledColumn]==calledValue) called[i][calledColumn]=true;
            /*
             *   Print the updated BINGO card.
             */
            myTextArea.setText("");
            myTextArea.append(toStringBingoCard(bingoCard,called));
            System.out.println(toStringBingoCard(bingoCard,called));

         } // while
         myTextArea.append("\n\nBINGO!!");

      } // main

      //======================================================================================================

      /*
       *   This method is just here for purposes of testing the program while it is being developed
       */
      public static void printArray (Integer[] a) {
         for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
            System.out.print(" "+ a[i].intValue());
         System.out.println();
      }
      /*
       *   Fill an array of Integers with 15 numbers with a given starting value.
       */
      public static void fillRow(Integer[] theRow, int startValue){
         for (int i = 0; i< 15; i++)
            theRow[i]= new Integer(startValue++);
      }
      /*
       *   Take the array of sequential Integers and put them in random order.
       */
      public static void randomize (Integer[] theArray) {
         Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(theArray));
      }
      /*
       *  The BINGO card needs only five of the shuffled numbers, so just put in the first five.
       */
      public static void putRowInBingoCard(Integer[][]card, int column, Integer[] row){
         for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
            card[i][column] = row[i];
      }
      /*
       *   Print the BINGO card.
       */
      public static void printBingoCard(Integer[][] bcard,boolean[][] called) {
         System.out.println(" B     I     N     G     O");
         for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<5;j++) {

               if (i==2 && j==2) System.out.print("<**>");
               else if (called[i][j]) System.out.print("<"+bcard[i][j]+">");
               else
                  System.out.print(" "+bcard[i][j]+" ");
               if (bcard[i][j]<10) System.out.print("   ");
               else System.out.print("  ");


            } // for j   
            System.out.println();   
         }  // for i      
      } //printBingoCard

      public static String toStringBingoCard(Integer[][] bcard,boolean[][] called) {
         String returnString="";
         returnString+= (" B     I     N     G     O \n");
         for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<5;j++) {

               if (i==2 && j==2) returnString+= ("<**>");
               else if (called[i][j]) returnString+= ("<"+bcard[i][j]+">");
               else
                  returnString+= (" "+bcard[i][j]+" ");
               if (bcard[i][j]<10) returnString+= ("   ");
               else returnString+= ("  ");


            } // for j   
            returnString+= "\n";   
         }  // for i  
         return returnString;
      } //toStringBingoCard

      public static boolean winner(boolean[][] called){
         boolean iAmAWinner = true;
         // winner in a row?
         for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<5;j++)
               iAmAWinner &= called[i][j];
            if(iAmAWinner) return true;
            else 
               iAmAWinner= true;
         } //for

         // winner in a column?
         for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<5;j++)
               iAmAWinner &= called[j][i];
            if(iAmAWinner) return true;
            else 
               iAmAWinner= true;
         } //for

         // winner in a diagonal?
         iAmAWinner=true;
         for (int i=0;i<5;i++) 
            iAmAWinner &= called[i][i];
            if(iAmAWinner) return true;

         iAmAWinner=true;
         for (int i=4;i>=0;i--) 
            iAmAWinner &= called[i][4-i];
            if(iAmAWinner) return true;


         return false;
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a working code, even if not in ideal shape, you should not try to impose preconceived *architecture* on it. Instead make small changes that do not change behavior, but takes you to your goal one step closer, or alleviate one problem. This method of evolving code while maintaining functionality is called **Refactoring**.

This is a number of small changes I made. I try give the names of automatic refactorings from Eclipse as much as I can.

1. Remove `extend Jframe` from Bingo
2. Extract method: called column parsing to `int calledColumnOf(String)` method
3. Extract method: called value parsing to `int calledValueOf(String)`
4. Introduce parameter object: toStringBingoCard(bingoCard, called) --> toStringBingoCard(new BingoCard(bingoCard, called))
5. Move method: toStringBingoCard -> BingoCard.toString

   - Copy&paste (only for a moment) `toStringBingoCard` to `toStringBingoCard_temp`
   - Override `toString` as just `return toStringBingoCard_temp(this);`
   - Inline method `toStringBingoCard_temp`
   - change body of `toStringBingoCard` as jus `return bingoCard.toString()`
   - Inline method `toStringBingoCard`
6. Extract local variable: `BingoCard theBingoCard = new BingoCard(bingoCard, called)`
7. Remove unused method: `printBingoCard`
8. Remove unused method: `printArray`
9. Extract method: the loop that updates `called` to `void numberCalled(Integer[][], boolean[][] ...)`
10. Make `numberCalled` and instance method of `BingoCard` as with `toString`
11. Introduce parameter object: `numberCalled` to `BingoNumber`
12. Extract method: code to get called number to `getCalledNumber`
13. Move method: getCalledNumber to a class `NumberCaller`, make it an instance method.
14. Extract method: extract everything in the `main(...)` except initialization to a method called `gameLoop`
15. Introduce parameter object: `theBingoCard`, `bingoCardView`, `numberCaller` to `BingoGame`
16. Move method: make `gameLoop` and instance method of `BingoGame`
17. Move method: `getInitialCard` and helpers to a new class `BingoCardFactory`.
18. Rename method:  `getInitialCard` to `create`.
19. Move method: `createView` to a new class `BingoViewFactory`.
20. Rename method:  `createView` to `create`.
21. Encapsulate field: `BingoNumber`s fields. no setters.
22. Encapsulate field: `BingoGame`s fields. no setters.

End result thus far:

```
public class Bingo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BingoCard theBingoCard = BingoCardFactory.create();
        BingoCardView bingoCardView = BingoViewFactory.creteView();
        NumberCaller numberCaller = new NumberCaller();

        BingoGame bingoGame = new BingoGame(theBingoCard, bingoCardView, numberCaller);

        bingoGame.gameLoop();
    }
}


public class BingoCard {
    private Integer[][] bcard;
    private boolean[][] called;

    public BingoCard(Integer[][] bcard, boolean[][] called) {
        this.bcard = bcard;
        this.called = called;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
           // former toStringBingoCard method....
    }

    public void numberCalled(BingoNumber bingoNumber) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        if (this.bcard[i][bingoNumber.getColumn()] == bingoNumber.getValue())
            this.called[i][bingoNumber.getColumn()] = true;
    }

    public boolean isWinner() {
           // former winner method....
    }
}


public class BingoCardFactory {
    public static BingoCard create() {
        Integer[][] bingoCard = new Integer[5][5];
        boolean[][] called = new boolean[][] {
                { false, false, false, false, false },
                { false, false, false, false, false },
                { false, false, true, false, false },
                { false, false, false, false, false },
                { false, false, false, false, false } };

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Integer[] row = new Integer[15];
            fillRow(row, i * 15 + 1);
            randomize(row);
            putRowInBingoCard(bingoCard, i, row);
        }

        BingoCard theBingoCard = new BingoCard(bingoCard, called);
        return theBingoCard;
    }

    private static void fillRow(Integer[] theRow, int startValue) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            theRow[i] = new Integer(startValue++);
    }

    private static void randomize(Integer[] theArray) {
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(theArray));
    }

    private static void putRowInBingoCard(Integer[][] card, int column,
            Integer[] row) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            card[i][column] = row[i];
    }

}

public class BingoCardView {
    private JTextArea myTextArea;

    public BingoCardView(JTextArea myTextArea) {
        this.myTextArea = myTextArea;
    }

    public void updateBingoCardView(BingoCard theBingoCard) {
        this.myTextArea.setText(theBingoCard.toString());
    }
    public void showWinMessage() {
        this.myTextArea.append("\n\nBINGO!!");
    }
}

public class BingoGame {
    private BingoCard bingoCard;
    private BingoCardView bingoCardView;
    private NumberCaller numberCaller;

    public BingoGame(BingoCard bingoCard, BingoCardView bingoCardView,
            NumberCaller numberCaller) {
       //......
    }

    public void gameLoop() {
        this.bingoCardView.updateBingoCardView(this.bingoCard);

        while (!this.bingoCard.isWinner()) {
            BingoNumber bingoNumber = this.numberCaller.getCalledNumber();
            this.bingoCard.numberCalled(bingoNumber);

            this.bingoCardView.updateBingoCardView(this.bingoCard);
            System.out.println(this.bingoCard.toString());

        } 
        this.bingoCardView.showWinMessage();
    }
}

public class BingoNumber {
    private int column;
    private int value;

    public BingoNumber(int column, int value) {
        this.column = column;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getColumn() {
        return column;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

public class BingoViewFactory {
    public static BingoCardView creteView() {
        JFrame myBingoGUI;
        myBingoGUI = new JFrame();
        myBingoGUI.setSize(250, 250);
        myBingoGUI.setLocation(400, 400);
        myBingoGUI.setTitle("BINGO");
        myBingoGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myBingoGUI.setVisible(true);
        Container myContentPane = myBingoGUI.getContentPane();
        JTextArea myTextArea = new JTextArea();
        myTextArea.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        myContentPane.add(myTextArea);
        BingoCardView bingoCardView = new BingoCardView(myTextArea);
        return bingoCardView;
    }

}

public class NumberCaller {
    public BingoNumber getCalledNumber() {
        String calledNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "Enter a BINGO call:");
        int calledColumn = calledColumnOf(calledNumber);
        int calledValue = calledValueOf(calledNumber);

        BingoNumber bingoNumber = new BingoNumber(calledColumn, calledValue);
        return bingoNumber;
    }

    private static int calledValueOf(String calledNumber) {
        int calledValue = Integer.parseInt(calledNumber.substring(1,
                calledNumber.length()));
        return calledValue;
    }

    private static int calledColumnOf(String calledNumber) {
        int calledColumn = -1;
        if (Character.toUpperCase(calledNumber.charAt(0)) == 'B')
            calledColumn = 0;
        if (Character.toUpperCase(calledNumber.charAt(0)) == 'I')
            calledColumn = 1;
        if (Character.toUpperCase(calledNumber.charAt(0)) == 'N')
            calledColumn = 2;
        if (Character.toUpperCase(calledNumber.charAt(0)) == 'G')
            calledColumn = 3;
        if (Character.toUpperCase(calledNumber.charAt(0)) == 'O')
            calledColumn = 4;
        return calledColumn;
    }
}
```

**We can go on still much further.** There still remains many things to be fixed. But in this state each code snippet is still recognizable from the original, to me at least.

Note, keeping to single responsibility principle, we ended up with more classes than initially asked for.

Separating classes according to functionality allows us to further modify our program more easily.

See for example, how easy would it be to change the view to use console instead of a JFrame.

A view does not *extend* `JFrame` or anything. It can be a frame, many frames, just console, or a network server. We do not know or care.

Same goes for the number caller also. It is quite easy to re-imagine this program as one of the clients of a server, where numbers are called centrally.

Next on the refactoring list should be, before altering behavior, extracting interfaces of these classes, such that it follows LID part of [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29).

Comment: I might have got bored and skipped some steps. I can explaing any steps that you cannot follow.

Answer (score 8):

### Review of Existing Code

- **Not object oriented:** As you probably already realize, your code is written in a procedural style, not object-oriented, which is the norm in Java.  You can tell because every function is `static`.  Note that although you declared `public class Bingo extends JFrame`, it runs just the same if you remove `extends JFrame`.  What's actually happening is that your `myBingoGUI` is the `JFrame`.
- **Prefer unboxed types:** Unless you have a good reason to use boxed types (`Integer`), you should use the unboxed primitive instead (`int`).  Boxed types make your code clumsy and incur unnecessary overhead.  Although you do need to use an `ArrayList<Integer>` to take advantage of `Collections.shuffle()` while randomizing the board, I would still store the board using an unboxed `int[][]`.
- **Initialization of `called`:** This takes less code:

  ```
  boolean[][] called = new boolean[5][5];
  called[5/2][5/2] = true;
  ```
- **Helper functions should be `private`:** Some of your functions are obviously intended for internal use only — for example, `fillRow()`, `randomize()`, `putRowInBingoCard()`.  You would never want any other code to call `putRowInBingoCard()`, so mark it `private` instead of `public`.  That goes for `randomize()` too — even though the function has some conceivable general utility, you wouldn't want to let a hypothetical Blackjack game use `Bingo.randomize()`, so don't expose it.
- **Misnomer:** `fillRow()` and `putRowInBingoCard()` actually work on a column, not a row.
- **Dead code:** `printBingoCard()` is never used.  Likewise with `printArray()`, as you noted.
- **Simplification:**  The code to assign `calledColumn` and `calledValue` is unnecessarily verbose.  The following is equivalent:

  ```
  int calledColumn = "BINGO".indexOf(Character.toUpperCase(calledNumber.charAt(0)));
  int calledValue = Integer.parseInt(calledNumber.substring(1));
  ```
- **Error handling:** If you input an empty string, it crashes with a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  If you give it just a number, it crashes with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  If you hit "Cancel" in the input dialog, it crashes with a `NullPointerException`.  (I would expect it to exit gracefully — call `dispose()` on the frame and `break` from the loop.)
- **Use a `StringBuilder`:** For repeated concatenation, use a `StringBuilder` for efficiency.
- **Naming convention for predicates:** In Java, a convention is to name a method `isSomething()` if the method takes no arguments, performs a test with no side effects, and returns a boolean.  Therefore, you should rename `winner()` to `isWinner()`.

### OOP Refactoring: First step

Notice that you pass the arrays `bingoCard` and `called` nearly everywhere.  That is the state that should be stored as instance variables in a `BingoCard` object.  I'll provide an outline of a `BingoCard` class for you to fill in:

```
public class BingoCard {
    private int[][] numbers;
    private boolean[][] called;

    public BingoCard() {
        numbers = new int[5][5];
        called = new boolean[5][5];
        called[5/2][5/2] = true;

        // Fill in numbers randomly as appropriate
        ...
    }

    public String toString() {
        ...
    }

    public boolean isWinner() {
        ...
    }

    public void mark(String calledNumber) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        ...
    }

    // Let's keep this here for now...
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        BingoCard card = new BingoCard();

        JFrame myBingoGUI;
        myBingoGUI=new JFrame();
        myBingoGUI.setSize(250, 250);
        myBingoGUI.setLocation(400, 400);
        myBingoGUI.setTitle("BINGO");
        myBingoGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myBingoGUI.setVisible(true);
        Container myContentPane = myBingoGUI.getContentPane();
        JTextArea myTextArea = new JTextArea();
        myTextArea.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN,14));
        myContentPane.add(myTextArea);

        myTextArea.setText(card.toString());
        System.out.println(card);

        // Play the game:   
        String error = "";
        String calledNumber = null;
        while (!card.isWinner() &&
               null != (calledNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, error + "Enter a BINGO call:")) {
            try {
                card.mark(calledNumber);
                error = "";
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException badCall) {
                error = "Invalid input: " + badCall.getMessage() + "\n";
            }

            // Print the updated BINGO card.
            myTextArea.setText(card.toString());
            System.out.println(card);

       }
       if (card.isWinner()) {
           myTextArea.append("\n\nBINGO!!");
       }
       if (null == calledNumber) {
           myBingoUI.dispose();
       }
    }
}
```

If you need to, you can add helper methods.  Remember, however, such helper methods should not be part of the class's interface, and should therefore be marked `private`.  (Personally, I don't think that helpers are needed, when about a dozen lines of code in the constructor would suffice.)

### Second Step: Separate UI from Model

The purpose of the `BingoCard` class is to represent the state of a card.  The next step is to purge UI code from `BingoCard`.  You should then be able to reuse the same `BingoCard` for a text console UI, a Swing UI, or a web-based UI.

The `BingoCard` and its UI should be loosely coupled.  The UI needs to know when the state of a `BingoCard` has changed, so that it can redraw it.  A common mechanism for this communication is to use a **listener**.  Augment `BingoCard` with the following members:

```
public class BingoCard {
    public static interface Listener {
        void handleBingoCardChanged(BingoCard card);
    }

    private HashSet<Listener> listeners = new HashSet<Listener>;

    // ... the previously developed the BingoCard code here ...

    public void addListener(Listener l) {
        this.listeners.add(l);
    }

    public void removeListener(Listener l) {
        this.listeners.remove(l);
    }

    private void fireChangeEvent() {
        for (Listener l : this.listeners) {
            l.handleBingoCardChanged(this);
        }
    }
}
```

You should be able to figure out where to call `fireChangeEvent()`.

Then you can implement the UI as

```
public class BingoUI extends JFrame implements BingoCard.Listener {
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public BingoUI(BingoCard card) {
        // Rough outline
        this.setSize(...);
        ...
        this.textArea = new JTextArea();
        card.addChangeListener(this);
        this.textArea.setText(card.toString());
    }

    public void handleBingoCardChanged(BingoCard card) {
        this.textArea.setText(card.toString());
        if (card.isWinner()) {
            this.textArea.append("\n\nBINGO!!");
        }
    }
}
```

At this point, you could implement a `main()` method in `BingoUI`.  The initialization code will be much shorter, since you'll simply be calling the `BingoCard` and `BingoUI` constructors.  The main loop will be not much different.

### Generalizing to Multiple Players

I'll leave you with a challenge to implement a two-player game:

```
public class BingoMain {
    public BingoMain(int players) { ... }
    public void play() { ... }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BingoMain(2).play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sanity check: When you're done, `BingoCard` should only need to import `java.util.*`; `BingoUI` should only need to import `java.awt.*` and `javax.swing.*`.

Comment: I don't really see, using what you call boxed types, as being clumsy. I can possible see it having extra overhead at runtime, but question if it has that much of an impact.  I think this is more a personal preference thing, but I'm willing to be persuaded otherwise.  Of coarse, I'm just nit picking a bit here, as either way doesn't hurt, in my opinion. Great answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your choice of classes to split the code in to is a little off, in my opinion. I would create three classes and an interface...

The interface would look like this:

```
package bingo;

public interface BingoCardListener {
    public void setup(String name, int columns, int rows, int[][] values);
    public void called(int col, int row, int value);
    public void complete(boolean winner);
}
```

This is used by the `BingoCard` class to tell anyone who's interested in what is happening to it.

The three classes I would have are:

1. `BingoMain` -> The `main()` method, and the control flow for selecting (and notifying) numbers.
2. `BingoCard` -> This controls what the card state is. Changes to the state will be communicated to any listeners.
3. `BingoCardPanel` -> This is the visual representation of the `BingoCard`. It implements the `BingoCardListener` interface.

I have taken the liberty of adding 5 cards (and their panels) to the system. It makes the logic for why things are done this way more sensible.

I have messed around with a few things in your code, but here are the three classes I have. Note, each `BingoCard` class chooses its own values, and manages its own state. The logic about what is selected and whether it wins or not is completely contained within `BingoCard`.

`BingoCardPanel` is purely a display tool. It does not contain any Bingo logic, but it changes the display state to match the `BingoCard`.

`BingoMain` is the main method only (and some constants).

I have put everything in the package 'bingo'.

The BingoCard class is a logical place to start:

```
package bingo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class BingoCard {

    public static int[] randomCol(int startValue, final int cols, final int rows, final int colrange){
        // this method essentially chooses 5 random values from a set of 15.
        int[] candidates = new int[colrange];
        for (int i = 0; i < candidates.length; i++) {
            candidates[i] = startValue + i;
        }
         // shuffle the candidates. If only there was an Arrays.shuffle(...).
        final Random rand = new Random(System.nanoTime());
        // Fischer-Yates shuffle.
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle
        int i = candidates.length;
        while (--i > 0) {
            int tmp = candidates[i];
            int swap = rand.nextInt(i + 1);
            candidates[i] = candidates[swap];
            candidates[swap] = tmp;
        }
        // pull the first count values from the suffled result.
        return Arrays.copyOf(candidates, rows);
    }

    private final boolean[][] called; // = new boolean[COLS][ROWS];
    private int remaining; // how many values need to be called....
    private final int[][] values; // = new int[COLS][];
    private final String name;
    private final ArrayList<BingoCardListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    private final int rows, cols;

    public BingoCard(final String name, final int columns, final int rows, final int colrange) {
        this.name = name;
        this.cols = columns;
        this.rows = rows;
        called = new boolean[columns][rows];
        called[columns / 2][rows / 2] = true;
        remaining = columns * rows - 1;
        values = new int[columns][];
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            values[i] = randomCol((i * colrange) + 1, columns, rows, colrange);
        }
    }

    public void addListener(BingoCardListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);

        // listener has been added. Let's catch it up with our current state.
        listener.setup(name, cols, rows, values);

        for (int c = 0; c < called.length; c++) {
            for (int r = 0; r < called[c].length; r++) {
                if (called[c][r]) {
                    listener.called(c, r, values[c][r]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean called(final int col, final int value) {
        for (int r = 0; r < values[col].length; r++) {
            if (values[col][r] == value) {
                // we have a match;
                if (!called[col][r]) {
                    called[col][r] = true;
                    remaining--;
                    for (BingoCardListener listener : listeners) {
                        listener.called(col, r, value);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("For some reason value " + value + " has been called multiple times");
                }
            }
        }
        return remaining <= 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
                if (called[c][r]) {
                    sb.append(String.format(" < %02d > ", values[c][r]));
                } else {
                    sb.append(String.format("   %02d   ", values[c][r]));
                }
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public void gameOver() {
        for (BingoCardListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.complete(remaining <= 0);
        }
    }

}
```

The `toString()` method is perhaps the most complicated ... ;-) Kidding, the `randomCol()` method is the most complex, but there are other ways to do it and I don't like converting `int`s to `Integer`s and messing with `Collections.shuffle()` when I don't have to.

The `BingoCardPanel` is the next logical thing to show. It is actually quite simple, when you get around the fact that it really only contains a 2D array of Labels. The order the array is initialized is row-at-a-time. This is different to the `BingoCard` which does things column-at-a-time. This is OK, though, and makes sense for displaying things...

Really there's nothing complicated in this class except for a potential bug if you ever use more than 5 columns (`"BINGO".substring(6,1)` will fail - fix it):

```
package bingo;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicBorders;

public class BingoCardPanel extends JPanel implements BingoCardListener {

    private final JPanel valuepanel = new JPanel();
    private final JLabel namelabel = new JLabel("Unknown");
    private JLabel[][] labels = null;

    public BingoCardPanel() {
        super();
        setBorder(BasicBorders.getInternalFrameBorder());
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 5));
        add(namelabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(valuepanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    public void setup(String name, int columns, int rows, int[][] values) {
        namelabel.setText(name);
        namelabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(rows + 1, columns, 5, 5);

        String bingo = "BINGO";
        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(bingo.substring(i, i+1));
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            valuepanel.add(label);
        }
        valuepanel.setLayout(layout);
        labels = new JLabel[columns][rows];
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
                labels[c][r] = new JLabel("" + values[c][r]);
                labels[c][r].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                valuepanel.add(labels[c][r]);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void called(final int col, final int row, int value) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                labels[col][row].setOpaque(true);
                labels[col][row].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void complete(final boolean winner) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                setBackground(winner ? Color.GREEN : Color.RED);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Finally, `BingoMain` does the control loops. I have added some validation, and other controls. Note, it is now only a single main method.

```
package bingo;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



public class BingoMain extends JFrame {

    private static final int ROWS = 5;
    private static final int COLS = 5;
    private static final int MAX_BINGO = 15 * COLS;

    public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

//        "BINGO".substring(6,1);

        JFrame myBingoGUI=new JFrame();
        myBingoGUI.setSize(600, 600);
        myBingoGUI.setLocation(100, 100);
        myBingoGUI.setTitle("BINGO");
        myBingoGUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container myContentPane = myBingoGUI.getContentPane();
        myContentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 4));

        BingoCard[] cards = new BingoCard[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
            cards[i] = new BingoCard("Card " + (i + 1), COLS, ROWS, MAX_BINGO / COLS);
            BingoCardPanel cpanel = new BingoCardPanel();
            cards[i].addListener(cpanel);
            myContentPane.add(cpanel);
        }

        myBingoGUI.setVisible(true);

        System.out.println(cards[0]);
        System.out.println();
        /*
         *   Play the game:   
         */
        boolean winner = false;
        while (!winner) {
            String error = "";
            int calledValue = -1;
            int calledColumn=-1;
            do {
                String calledNumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, error + " Enter a BINGO call:");
                error = "";
                calledColumn = -1;
                calledValue = -1;

                if (calledNumber == null) {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    error = "Cancelled... ";
                    continue;
                }
                /*
                 *   The first character of the input string is converted to a column number between 0 and 4
                 */
                if (Character.toUpperCase(calledNumber.charAt(0))=='B') calledColumn=0;
                if (Character.toUpperCase(calledNumber.charAt(0))=='I') calledColumn=1;
                if (Character.toUpperCase(calledNumber.charAt(0))=='N') calledColumn=2;
                if (Character.toUpperCase(calledNumber.charAt(0))=='G') calledColumn=3;
                if (Character.toUpperCase(calledNumber.charAt(0))=='O') calledColumn=4;
                if (calledColumn < 0) {
                    error = "Called Column '" + Character.toUpperCase(calledNumber.charAt(0)) + "' must be one of BINGO";
                } else {
                    /*
                     *  The remainder of the input string is converted to an integer
                     */
                    try {
                        calledValue = Integer.parseInt(calledNumber.substring(1,calledNumber.length()));
                        if (calledValue < 1 || calledValue > MAX_BINGO) {
                            error = "Illegal value " + calledValue + " (1 <= value <= " + MAX_BINGO + ")";
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                        error = "Illegal number " + calledNumber.substring(1,calledNumber.length());
                    }
                }
            } while (error.length() != 0);
            /*
             *   The matrix of called numbers is update to show the number has been called.
             */
            for (BingoCard card : cards) {
                if (card.called(calledColumn, calledValue)) {
                    winner = true;
                }
            }
            if (winner) {
                for (BingoCard card : cards) {
                    card.gameOver();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(cards[0]);
            System.out.println();

        } // while

    } // main

}
```

Comment: very helpful thank you. Was able to start most of it. I am trying to add file and quit buttons at the top of the window in a menuBar. I can get the file and quit buttons on, but I am having trouble adding the listener, partly because I am not sure where in the code or class it would go. I would post the code I'm trying to use but not sure how. Thanks